# Pyramid server not serving flash files

Tags: python, flash, pyramid

I am running this python pyramid server. Strangely, when I moved my server code to a different machine, pserve stopped serving flash videos in my static folder. Whereas it serves other static files, like images, fine ! What could be a reason for this ?

Comment: Please respond to answers

Answer (score 3):

Pyramid's static views serve up files with a content-type determined via python's `mimetypes` module. Most likely you'll need to add support for the extra video types to your installation at startup. Specifically something along the lines of the following, somewhere in your code.

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.init()
mimetypes.add_type(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

I possibly ran into a similar problem on my pyramid app.  I'm using TinyMCE and had placed the files in the static folder.  Everything worked on my dev server, but moved to test and prod and static .html files related to TinyMCE couldn't be found.

My web host had me add a symlink basically I think hardcoding to the server software (nginix in this case) the web address to my static HTML to the server path and that worked.

I'll have to check out the mimetypes thing, though, too.